# How to convert this complex json in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, arraylist

I want to convert this Json file to kotlin :

```
   {
    "results": {
        "ALL": {
            "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
            "currencySymbol": "Lek",
            "id": "ALL"
        },
        "XCD": {
            "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
            "currencySymbol": "$",
            "id": "XCD"
        }
    }
}


interface Api {

    @GET(ApiEndPoints.GET_CURRENCIES)
    suspend fun getCurrencies(
        @Query(Constants.API_KEY)
        countryCode: String = ApiEndPoints.API_KEY,
        @Query(Constants.FROM_TO)
        apiKey:String = "USD_USD",
        @Query("compact")
        compact:String = "ultra"
    ):CurrencyResults

}
```

MODEL:

```
data class CurrencyResults(
    val results: Map<String, Currency>
)

data class Currency(
    val currencyName: String,
    val currencySymbol: String,
    val id: String,
)
```

View Model:

```
 init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //Should get result here 

        }
    }
```

It's JSON contains over 100 Object like this snippet above ! I cant get it all here
And When I'm trying to convert it to kotlin I get error or null or must write over 100 class to detect all json objects!
I want to convert it to a Currency model class To hold the name and the symbol and id !
What can I do ?

Comment: How are you tryin to convert this json file?

Comment: This is my question

Comment: use this link to convert json response to data class. https://json2kt.com/

Comment: @DnyaneshwarPatil this tool might help a little bit with writing the code itself, but it won't help define how it should be. It clearly cannot detect when the JSON keys of an object are dynamic and pointing to values of the same type, in which case that object should be represented as a map and not a data class. Also it seems to generate multiple identical data classes instead of reusing the same one.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```kotlin
data class CurrencyResults(
    val results: Map<String, Currency>
)

data class Currency(
    val currencyName: String,
    val currencySymbol: String,
    val id: String,
)
```

Comment: How can I use it ? 

@GET(ApiEndPoints.GET_CURRENCIES)
    suspend fun getCurrencies(
        @Query(Constants.API_KEY)
        countryCode: String = ApiEndPoints.API_KEY,
        @Query(Constants.FROM_TO)
        apiKey:String = "USD_USD",
        @Query("compact")
        compact:String = "ultra"
    ):CurrencyResults

When I use it like this and call it from viewModel it returns empty list ! 
Can you tell me full example please

Answer (score 0):

This model should work :

```
data class Currencies(val results : Map<String, Currency>)

data class Currency(val currencyName : String, val currencySymbol : String, val id : String)
```

You do not mention how you convert them, using a 3rd party library or otherwise, however it is usually standard where you have unknown keys and consistent Json Objects to use a `Map<K, V>` model structure.

Comment: How can I use it ? 

@GET(ApiEndPoints.GET_CURRENCIES)
    suspend fun getCurrencies(
        @Query(Constants.API_KEY)
        countryCode: String = ApiEndPoints.API_KEY,
        @Query(Constants.FROM_TO)
        apiKey:String = "USD_USD",
        @Query("compact")
        compact:String = "ultra"
    ):CurrencyResults

When I use it like this and call it from viewModel it returns empty list ! 
Can you tell me full example please

Comment: full code from you first in your question ... not in comments.